# How to define a wrapper of macro time in Common Lisp

Tags: profiling, common-lisp

I'm newbie on Lisp, I want to print the output of time into a file(/tmp/foo.txt), so I define a wrapper function about time as following:

```
(defun my-time(form)
  (lisp::with-open-file (*trace-output* "/tmp/foo.txt"
                                           :direction :output
                                           :if-exists :append
                                           :if-does-not-exist :create)
                       (time(form))))
(defun test(n)
  (dotimes (i n) (format t "this is test ~a.~&" i)))
```

But, when I run (my-time (test 2)), following error appear:
**Error: Undefined function FORM called with arguments ().**

It's OK when I do this test: (time (test 2))

Could someone give me some clues?

Comment: There is no `LISP` package in Common Lisp anymore. It's now `COMMON-LISP`.

Comment: Thanks for your reminder, there is package nickname in my environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### What Happens

Your `(test 2)` form is being executed before `my-time` runs, because arguments of a function are always evaluated before they get into a function. So as it written, it won't work as you want. But this alone doesn't give you any errors, just incorrect measurement.

Next, what happens inside of your `my-time` function: you run a form `form`. Unless you have defined it beforehand, there is no such form - so you get an error.

Every time Lisp encounters a list, it tries to execute it. List, first element of which is a symbol that represents name of a function or macro called *form*. Even when you use a quote it does not cancel this rule: `quote` form gets executed and it returns its contents as a result.

```
(form element ...)
;^^^^ - from namespace for functions
```

There are two namespaces in Common Lisp. Namespace with executable symbols and namespace for variables. Inside of `my-time` you have variable `form`, but this symbol is located in namespace for variables, not for functions. Thus you get an error.

### How to Fix

There are two ways how to solve your problem:

- Use a Macro;
- Wrap your form with `lambda` and then execute it inside of `my-time` using `funcall`.

### Solution Involving Macro

You can use a macro, very similar to your function:

```
(defmacro my-time(&body body)
  `(with-open-file (*trace-output*
                    "/tmp/foo.txt"
                    :direction :output
                    :if-exists :append
                    :if-does-not-exist :create)
     (time (progn ,@body))))
```

This will work (if you're lucky enough and directory "temp" exists ;-)

### Solution Involving Function

First, define `my-time`:

```
(defun my-time (form)
  (with-open-file (*trace-output*
                   "/tmp/foo.txt"
                   :direction :output
                   :if-exists :append
                   :if-does-not-exist :create)
    (time (funcall form))))
```

Then let's try it:

```
(my-time (lambda nil (time 2)))
```

Works. My "foo.txt" file is full of statistical data now.

Comment: Solution involving macro is graceful, thanks for your detailed help.